# SWRevealViewController version 2.4.0 segue not working ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swrevealviewcontroller

In the previous version of SWRevealViewController I was creating a segue of `SWRevealViewControllerSegue class` and in the `prepareforSegue` I used the following code.

```
#pragma mark - Navigation
- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender
{
    if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] )
    {
        SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;
        swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {
            UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
            [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];

            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
        };

    }
}
```

> In the new version of SWRevealViewController,there is no segue of
>   SWRevealViewControllerSegue class.Instead there is a class called
>   SWRevealViewControllerSetSegue .I created a segue of this class but
>   the navigation is not happening.

The above code cannot be used in the new version as it is deprecated.What should I use in `prepareforSegue`?

What can I do to perform the navigation?PLease help.

Comment: this is given at example purpose, but it not required one for SWLRevalViewCOntroller

Comment: you don't need it to do, just create a custom segue and set classes from SWRevealViewController. There is Two classes for use `SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController` and `SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController` and it works . cheers happy coding

Comment: Then what is the difference between set controller and pushcontroller segue?

Comment: i think this question is awesome and will try to make changes on what i have been trying.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Subhash Sharma's comment is correct.We don't have to code anything in prepareforSegue for navigation.

> Just create a segue of type SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController
>   and perform this segue whenever needed.It simply works.

Comment: My issue was that the segue was not working in the newer version.I created a segue of SWRevealViewControllerSetSegue class but the navigation was not happening.And I thought that there should be some code in the prepareforsegue method for this segue to work.But it was my mistake that I used SWRevealViewControllerSetSegue instead of  SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController.it solved my question.

Comment: If you know the difference between set controller and pushcontroller ,please  explain it here.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code below**

```
 UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    SWRevealViewController *revealVC = (SWRevealViewController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"revealVCID"];
    [self presentViewController:revealVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([segue isKindOfClass:[SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController class] ]){

        UIViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];                
        UINavigationController *navCtrl = (UINavigationController *) self.revealViewController.frontViewController;        
        [navCtrl setViewControllers:@[dvc] animated:NO];        
        [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
UIStoryboard *sb;

if (IS_IPAD) {
    sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad_Main" bundle:nil];
} else {
    sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
}


if ([segue isKindOfClass:[SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController class]]) {

    UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
    [navController setViewControllers: @[[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"create"]] animated: NO ];
    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];

}
```